# Python - Solve Ax=b using Gradient Descent

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, linear-algebra, gradient-descent

Want to solve Ax=b , find x , with known matrices A ( `nxn` and b `nx1` , A being pentadiagonial matrix , trying for different `n` . You can see how they are set here :
[image]

[image]

I want to use **Gradient Descent** in order to solve the linear system . I see that using this method for solving `Ax=b` is essentially trying to minimize the quadratic function

```
f(x) = 0.5*x^t*A*x - b^t*x.
```

I see a wikipedia example for

```
f(x)=x^{4}-3x^{3}+2
```

will be something like :

```
next_x = 6  # We start the search at x=6
gamma = 0.01  # Step size multiplier
precision = 0.00001  # Desired precision of result
max_iters = 10000  # Maximum number of iterations

# Derivative function
def df(x):
    return 4 * x ** 3 - 9 * x ** 2


for _i in range(max_iters):
    current_x = next_x
    next_x = current_x - gamma * df(current_x)

    step = next_x - current_x
    if abs(step) <= precision:
        break

print("Minimum at ", next_x)

# The output for the above will be something like
# "Minimum at 2.2499646074278457"
```

so is it possible to just replace the `return` with `0.5*(A+A.T.conj())*x - b` (which is the derivative of `f(x) = 0.5*x^t*A*x - b^t*x` (which itself it's the function we get for Ax=b). I tried this but didn't got right results for `x` . You can see my full code here :

```
import time
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
from scipy.linalg import solve_triangular

import math

start_time = time.time()




n=100

################## AAAAA matrix #############################################
A = np.zeros([n, n], dtype=float)  # initialize to f zeros

# ------------------first row
A[0][0] = 6
A[0][1] = -4
A[0][2] = 1
# ------------------second row
A[1][0] = -4
A[1][1] = 6
A[1][2] = -4
A[1][3] = 1
# --------------two last rows-----
# n-2 row
A[- 2][- 1] = -4
A[- 2][- 2] = 6
A[- 2][- 3] = -4
A[- 2][- 4] = 1
# n-1 row
A[- 1][- 1] = 6
A[- 1][- 2] = -4
A[- 1][- 3] = 1

# --------------------------- from second to n-2 row --------------------------#
j = 0
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n - 4):
        break
    A[i][j] = 1
    j = j + 1

j = 1
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n - 3):
        break
    A[i][j] = -4
    j = j + 1

j = 2
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n - 2):
        break
    A[i][j] = 6
    j = j + 1

j = 3
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n - 1):
        break
    A[i][j] = -4
    j = j + 1

j = 4
for i in range(2, n - 2):
    if j == (n):
        break
    A[i][j] = 1
    j = j + 1
# -----------------------------end coding of 2nd to n-2 r-------------#
print("\nMatrix A is : \n", A)

####### b matrix ######################################
b = np.zeros(n,float).reshape((n,1))
b[0] = 3
b[1] = -1
#b[len(b) - 1] = 3
#b[len(b) - 2] = -1
b[[0,-1]]=3; b[[1,-2]]=-1

############ init x #####################
x = np.zeros(n,float).reshape((n,1))
#x = [0] * n
#x = np.zeros([n, 1], dtype=float)
print("\n x is ",x)

print("\nMatrix b is \n", b)
#####################################



# Derivative function
def df(x):
    a = 0.5 * (A + np.transpose(A))
    res = np.dot(a, x) - b
    return res

def steep(A,b,x):
    next_x = 6  # We start the search at x=6
    gamma = 0.01  # Step size multiplier
    precision = 0.00001  # Desired precision of result
    max_iters = 10000  # Maximum number of iterations


    for _i in range(max_iters):
        current_x = next_x
        next_x = current_x - gamma * df(current_x)

        step = next_x - current_x
        ass=abs(step)
        if ass.any() <= precision:
            break

    print("Minimum at ", next_x)
    return next_x

myx=steep(A,b,x)

print("\n myx is ",myx)




print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: You want to implement all the matrix operation yourself or with `numpy`?

Comment: yes , and like I said it would be something like find the minimum of a function only that because we have Ax=b , it would be the minimum the quadratic function f(x) = 0.5*x^t*A*x - b^t*x , I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, one way of simplifiying construction of coefficient matrix `A` may be to use [`np.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) and sum together each individual `k` diagonal matrix instead of using multiple `for` loops, so by taking `n=10` for instance

```
import numpy as np

# gradient descent parameters
gamma = 0.01          # step size multiplier
tol = 1e-5            # convergence tolerance for stopping criterion
max_iters = 1e6       # maximum number of iterations

# dimension of the problem
n = 10

A = np.diag(np.ones(n-2), k=-2) + np.diag(-4*np.ones(n-1), k=-1) + \
    np.diag(6*np.ones(n), k=0) + \
    np.diag(-4*np.ones(n-1), k=1) + np.diag(np.ones(n-2), k=2)

b = np.zeros(n)
b[0] = 3 ; b[1] = -1 ; b[n-1] = 3 ; b[n-2] = -1
```

Now, gradient descent (steepest descent) states that the **vector** `x_sol` which is solution of the system `Ax=b`, where `A` is **positive definite** and **symmetric**, is the minimal value of the quadratic form

```
def f(A,b,x):
    return 0.5*np.dot(np.dot(x,A),x)-np.dot(x,b)
```

So make sure to perform correct matrix multiplication (with `np.dot` function or `@` operator) and not python element-wise multiplication (with `*` operator) in the gradient evaluation `df` of this function `f` so that

```
def df(A,b,x):
    return np.dot(A,x)-b
```

However, note that because `A` is **symmetric**, `df` can be simplified and just returns the exact residual `np.dot(A,x)-b` instead of `0.5*np.dot(A.T,x) + 0.5*np.dot(A,x)-b`. You also need to specify an adequate stopping criterion, for instance by testing the euclidian norm of step distance with respect to your tolerance factor `tol`. Let's run this

```
# int: you chose 6 as initial guess
x0 = 6

def gradient_descent(A,b,x0):
        # initial guess vector x
        next_x = x0*np.ones(n) 
        # print initial f value 
        print('i = 0 ; f(x)= '+str(f(A,b,next_x)))
        i=1
        # convergence flag
        cvg = False           
        print('Starting descent')
        while i <= max_iters:
            curr_x = next_x
            next_x = curr_x - gamma * df(A,b,curr_x)

            step = next_x - curr_x
            # convergence test
            if np.linalg.norm(step,2)/(np.linalg.norm(next_x,2)+np.finfo(float).eps) <= tol:
                cvg = True
                break
            # print optionnaly f values while searching for minimum
            print('i = '+str(i)+' ; f(x)= '+str(f(A,b,next_x)))
    
            i += 1

    if cvg :
        print('Minimum found in ' + str(i) + ' iterations.')
        print('x_sol =',next_x)
    else :
        print('No convergence for specified parameters.')

    return next_x
```

which gives

```
x_sol = gradient_descent(A,b,x0)
>>> i = 0 ; f(x)= 48.0
>>> Starting descent
>>> i = 1 ; f(x)= 43.20999999999996
>>> i = 2 ; f(x)= 39.17663099999998
>>> i = 3 ; f(x)= 35.75573883350001
>>> i = 4 ; f(x)= 32.83351344396835
>>> i = 5 ; f(x)= 30.319690909679018
>>> i = 6 ; f(x)= 28.1423440799636
>>> ...
>>> i = 19144 ; f(x)= -1.99977775801747
>>> i = 19145 ; f(x)= -1.9997778660326588
>>> i = 19146 ; f(x)= -1.99977797399535
>>> i = 19147 ; f(x)= -1.99977808190557
>>> i = 19148 ; f(x)= -1.999778189763341
>>> Minimum found in 19149 iterations.
>>> x_sol = [1.00991626 1.02509014 1.04110403 1.05415009 1.0614195  1.0614195
1.05415009 1.04110403 1.02509014 1.00991626]
```

Finally, let's compare with direct solver `np.linalg.solve`:

```
np.allclose(np.linalg.solve(A,b),x_sol)
>>> True
```

Also, I would use [scipy.linalg.solveh_banded](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solveh_banded.html#scipy.linalg.solveh_banded) if gradient descent is not mandatory or upgrade this for better convergence into conjugate gradient method by making use of `A`-orthogonal vectors set as search directions with a good preconditioner (see this excellent [pdf](http://math.stmarys-ca.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Mike-Rambo.pdf) imo). Hope this helps.

Comment: nice , but shouldnt we create a new function in the part    for _i in range(max_iters): , and later call it to get the results ?

Comment: yes it's fine , just can it be optimized some more , since we have sparse matrix , it takes so much time to run for n=100 . Or maybe that's expected , cause that algorithm isn't that optimal

Comment: I would just use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solveh_banded.html#scipy.linalg.solveh_banded if gradient descent isn't a must used for you.

Comment: ok thanks , I will use the gradient descent also thanks for your time

Comment: Is it a coincidence that $df(A, b x)$ is in the same as residual $Ax-b$? The meaning of these two seem not related... it puzzled me a lot.